# PayPal Adaptive Payment SetPaymentOptions - does it work?

Tags: perl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been trying (fruitlessly!) to get **PayPals SetPaymentOptions API** feature to work, as per: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/

*FWIW* - I'm aware the below isn't truly JSON, but its the Perl object I'm creating - which gets converted into JSON before sending (its just easier to read like this, compared to having it all on one line =))

So far I create the initial payment using the "Pay" feature (https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay):

```
{
      requestEnvelope => { 
        detailLevel => "ReturnAll",
        errorLanguage =>  "en_US",
      },
      actionType => "PAY",
      currencyCode => "USD",
      receiverList => {
         receiver => [
           {
              amount => 65,
              email  => 'user1@gmail.com',
              paymentType => "GOODS",
              invoiceId => "test"
           },
            {
              amount => 15,
              email  => 'user2@gmail.com',
              paymentType => "GOODS",               
              invoiceId => "test 2"
           }
         ],  
      },
      returnUrl => 'http://xx.com/thanks.html',
      cancelUrl => 'http://xx.com/cancel.html',
}
```

This creates it fine, and I get returned back the **payKey** just fine. The problem starts when I try and add shipping/units prices/taxes etc via **SetPaymentOptions**. Here is an example request I'm making:

```
{
  payKey => $json_returned->{payKey},
  requestEnvelope => { 
          detailLevel => "ReturnAll",
          errorLanguage =>  "en_US",
  },  
  receiverOptions => [
      {
           customId => "foo123",
           receiver => {
              email => 'andy-facilitator@ultranerds.com'
           }, 
           invoiceData => {
             item => [{
                            name      => "ITEM1",
                            price     => 50,
                            itemCount => 2,
                            itemPrice => 25,
                          }],
              totalTax  => 5,
              totalShipping => 10,
           },
          SenderOptions  => {
              addressOverride => 1,
              requireShippingAddressSelection => 1
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

I then grab back that transaction to see if it all got saved ok, by using a **PaymentDetails** request (https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails)

This always comes back with no shipping, tax, unit numbers, etc. I'm at a real loss as to whats going on - because if I were to change (for example) the number of units in this 2nd request, or the delivery price... it gives me an error that the numbers don't match up! So it has to be recognizing it - but just not doing anything with it

I'm really at my witts end here (I wish they'd hurry up and get the REST APIs finished up - as they look more promising than this... but for now, I've got to make do with what we have here with the Adaptive Payments)

**UPDATE:**

Is this what you mean with regards to running the `ExecutePayment`?

```
my $pass_in_params = {
  payKey => $json_returned->{payKey},
  requestEnvelope => { 
          detailLevel => "ReturnAll",
          errorLanguage =>  "en_US",
  },
  actionType => "CREATE"
};
```

**WAHOO** - Finally got it working!  As per Andrews info, the reason I wasn't seeing the shipping/units/tax stuff with the `ExecutePayment` request, is because we hadn't sent them to the payment page yet (and you can't grab it until the payment is complete). With the Sandbox, you can login to a test account and see all the units etc perfectly.

Comment: Are you finalizing the payment with ExecutePayment prior to calling PaymentDetails?

Comment: Oh, you have to do that after you call **SetPaymentOptions**?

Comment: @AndrewAngel I tried doing the `PaymentDetails` request AFTER the `SetPaymentOptions` request, but I get an error: This payment request must be authorized by the sender at test.cgi line 16 . I'm passing in: `payKey => $json_returned->{payKey}, requestEnvelope => { detailLevel => "ReturnAll", errorLanguage =>  "en_US" }` ... what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: in my case executing isn't working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Pay with CREATE and then call SetPaymentOptions behind that, no payment occurs until you finish it up with ExecutePayment.  As such, when you call PaymentDetails there are no details to obtain.

Try calling ExecutePayment to finish things off and then see if PaymentDetails works better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So just to be sure, you are suggesting I do `Pay`, then `SetPaymentOptions`, then `ExecutePayment`, and finally (to test if it got saved ok), `PaymentDetails`?

Comment: Yes.  You shouldn't even be seeing any payment in the receiver account until after you run ExecutePayment.

Comment: Thanks - when I run it in that order though, I get:

`ERROR: This payment request must be authorized by the sender at test.cgi line 170.` (coming from the **ExecutePayment** request). When I do the "Pay" request, this is the correct action, yeah? `actionType => "PAY",`? (cos in some places it mentions using UPDATE.. but surely that wouldn't be called in the **Pay** request)

Comment: When using SetPaymentOptions the Pay request needs to be set to CREATE, not PAY.

Comment: Thanks - getting closer I feel! I now have this in the **Pay**: `actionType => "CREATE"` , but I still get this error when doing the **ExecutePayment** (after **SetPaymentOptions**): `This payment request must be authorized by the sender`

Comment: Sounds like you never logged in to authenticate the payment.

Comment: Mmm, so you have to log in, between these stages? Can't you run them all one after the other? Kinda seems pointless having to do them in more than 1 step? Or do you simply mean I need to "load" the page in the script before trying the Execute? i.e https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=xxxx . Sorry to be sure a PITA :)

Comment: At some point your buyer has to authorize the payment.  If you've sent them through a Preapproval flow, where they've signed in and agreed to your preapproval terms, then you could work with everything you're trying to do without any redirect because you'd include a preapproval key in your Pay request and that would handle the authentication.  Apparently that isn't happening, and no redirect/login happened to authenticate the payment either, hence the error you're getting back.

Comment: Mmm ok - well this is the logic I'm doing currently: 1) Fill out a `Pay` request (just basic email + amount), for multiple users 2) Then run `SetPaymentOptions` to update those transactions (with tax, delivery, units etc) 3) Trying to run `ExecutePayment` as per your suggestion (to update the shipping costs)   4) Doing a request for the payment back via `PaymentDetails`. I would then show them to link to paypal, where they would see the info. I'm a bit confused as to how else you can do it?

Comment: SetPaymentOptions is where you'd set the shipping costs.  ExecutePayment is what actually executes the payment once all the details and everything are prepared.

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant - I was updating the shipping with `SetPaymentOptions`, but that doesn't actually do anything to the transaction (if you go to the transaction URL, it just shows the whole price - not broken down). When I try and run `ExecutePayment`, that is when I get the error message

Comment: You won't see the details until it's done and you look at the transaction details in PayPal or pull them from the API.  Unfortunately, they don't show up in the review like Express Checkout does.  Again, though, that error is telling you exactly what's wrong, and I've explained why it's happening.  I'm not sure how much more I can say.

Comment: Ahhh ok - so I shouldn't see it there then. That would explain things then! I've accepted your answer - thanks for sticking it out =)